# How to assign an output to a label in a second form through the first form?

Tags: vb.net

I wanna show the output of the calculations in a second form but I am writing the code in the first form. How can I do it?

Comment: do you have any code to show what you have tried?

Comment: I got it. Thanks for helping
frmsummary.lbltotal = decTotalPay.Tostring("c")

Answer (score 0):

Use the parent form name in front of the control that you are trying to work with.  You may need to set the modifier to Friend.

Say that the label exists in form2 and you have code in form1 that is needing to change it. So you would do it like this: `form2.label.text = "the string value here"`

However, keep in mind that if the control was created or is owned by a different thread then the one that is trying to edit the control, you will receive a runtime exception.

To resolve that you will need to create a delegate for the calling sub or function.